# How to return a vector of objects from class to main.cpp

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a student class that has a function that reads student objects from a text file and adds them to a student Vector. This is ok and works perfect. I have this function in my student.cpp file. (I think this is correct).

How do I return this vector from student.cpp to the main where I can access the elements, edit them and sort etc..

***student.cpp***

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "q1studentType.h"


q1studentType::q1studentType(std::string sFN, std::string sLN, std::string ts)
{
    studentFName = sFN;
    studentLName = sLN;
    testScore = ts;
}

void q1studentType::printStudent()
{
    std::cout << studentFName << " " << studentLName << "\t(" << testScore << " / "<< grade << ")" << std::endl;
}


std::vector<q1studentType>  q1studentType::initStudents() {
    std::vector<q1studentType> students;
    std::ifstream inFile("students.txt");

    for (q1studentType i;
        getline(inFile, i.studentFName, ',')
        && getline(inFile, i.studentLName, ',')
        && getline(inFile, i.testScore)
        ; )
    {
        students.push_back(i);
        i.printStudent();
    }

    return students;
}
```

***Main***

```
int main() {

    //What I want to say in my head
    std::vector<q1studentType> students = q1studentType.initStudents();


}
```

Am I going about this in the right way? Thanks in advance

Comment: At first glance your code looks correct. What is the problem?

Comment: You can return a copy or a reference. You can edit the original values with a reference but you have to pay attention to the life time of the object.

Comment: Make initStudents static

Comment: BTW you can write `auto students = q1studentType.initStudents();` instead of `std::vector<q1studentType> students = q1studentType.initStudents();`

Comment: Your code is valid if `initStudents()` is a static function. Otherwise you should write: `q1studentType type; std::vector<q1studentType> students = type.initStudents();`

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the error message if any. Currently it is not clear what is the problem/quesiton

Comment: Thanks everyone and thanks @Jabberwocky for bringing the ```auto``` keyword to my attention. I never knew it existed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in the code:

Make initStudents() public and static in the declaration (typically in the header file q1studentType.h)

```
public: static std::vector<q1studentType>  q1studentType::initStudents();
```

Code in .cpp then looks ok to me.

And call it proper in the main.cpp

```
auto students = q1studentType::initStudents();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. When I try to add static I get an error 'a storage class may not be specified here'

Comment: @Cormac You need to add it to the code in the .h file, not the .cpp file

Comment: @Cormac updated the answer, make it proper declaration

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Thats great. Thank you for taking the time to answer and formatting the code in code boxes.

Comment: @Cormac You're welcome, best of luck with your class